# Yup validation in React - validate each element in array if it is a correct IPv4 or not

Tags: reactjs, arrays, validation, yup

I would like to validate a form that have a field that user must type an array of valid IP address.

I have a register schema like this:

```
const RegisterSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string().required('Username required'),
    password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
    email: Yup.string().required('Email is required'),
    ip_address: Yup.array()
        .of(Yup.string()
            .matches(
            "^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9]|)\d)\.?\b){4}$",
            'One or more IP addresses are not valid')
        )
        .required('IP is required'),
  });
```

However, in React form, the validation of checking each element in array is not working. Here is my expectation:

```
ip_address = ['1.1.1.1'] // true
ip_address = ['2.2.2'] // false
ip_address = ['3.3.3.3', '4.4.4'] // false
ip_address = ['5.5', '6.6.6.6'] // false
ip_address = ['7.7.7.7', '8.8.8.8'] // true
ip_address = ['9.9.9.9', 'abcd'] // false
ip_address = ['123.456.789.123', '10.10.10.10'] // false
```

Does someone have any solutions for this case?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your validation schema is that it's trying to match the entire array against the IP address pattern, instead of checking each individual element in the array. To achieve your expected validation you can use the `test` function which checks if the array is not empty `(!value)`, and then it uses the `every` method to iterate over each element in the array and validate that it matches the IP address pattern.

```
const RegisterSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  username: Yup.string().required('Username required'),
  password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
  email: Yup.string().required('Email is required'),
  ip_address: Yup.array()
    .test({
      name: 'ip-address',
      test: (value) => {
        if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
          return false; // Reject if it's not an array
        }

        if (value.length === 0) {
          return false; // Reject if the array is empty
        }

        // Check each IP address in the array
        return value.every(ip => /^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1\d|[1-9])\d)\.?\b){4}$/.test(ip));
      },
      message: 'One or more IP addresses are not valid',
    })
    .required('IP is required'),
});
```

Comment: I got an error "value.every is not a function" when submitting the form

Comment: Please check an updated version of code that checks if value is an array before applying the every function. This modification first checks if value is an array using Array.isArray(value). If it's not an array, it returns false immediately. If it is an array, then it proceeds to check the validity of each IP address using the every function.

Comment: It seems like ".of(...)" is not worked in my code, because the form is still invalid although I type an array of IPs with valid conditions, and the yup error message is not showed. Without "of(...)", the code is working fine

Comment: To handle arrays in Yup, you should use the .test() method directly on the array field rather than using .of() for individual array elements. I have updated my answer, please check.